# codeigniter pagination dropdown select filter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I have created a site where I have grouped items under projects. When the user selects a project from the provided dropdown menu and submits it the items that pertain to that project number a retrieved and sent back to the controller.

My Controller

```
public function dwg_list()
{
    $data['proj_num'] = $this->model_proj->proj_num_all();
    $num_row = 1;
    if ($this->input->post('project_no') != '0')
    {
        $data['result'] = $this->model_issue->list_dwg($this->input->post('project_no'));

        if (count($data['result']) > 0)
        {
            $num_row = count($data['result']);
        } else $num_row = 1;
    }

    $this->load->library('pagination');

    $config['base_url'] = base_url() . '/index.php/dwg_issue/dwg_list/page';
    $config['total_rows'] = $num_row;
    $config['per_page'] = 2; 

    $this->pagination->initialize($config); 



    $data['main_content'] = 'dwg_list';
    $this->load->view('includes/template.php', $data);

}
```

My View

```
<h1>This page displays all the registered drawings</h1>
<br>

<div id="body">
<div class="row">
        <div class="form-group-sm"><lable class="col-sm-2 control-label">Project number:</lable>
    <?php
        $js = 'onchange="this.form.submit()" class="form-control" id="focusInput"';
        echo form_open('dwg_issue/dwg_list');
        echo "<div class=\"col-xs-2\">" . form_dropdown('project_no',$proj_num, $this->input->post('project_no'),$js)."</div>";
        echo form_error('project_no', '<div class="col-xs-4"><div class="alert alert-danger fade in"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>','</div></div>');
    ?>
        </div>
        </div>
        <br>

<?php
echo "<noscript>".form_submit('submit','Submit')."</noscript>";
?>

        <table title="List of drawings" class="table table-hover" style="font-size: 14px">
            <caption><b>List of drawings</b></caption>
        <thead>
            <tr><th>Project number</th><th>Drawing number</th><th>Client drawing number</th>
                <th>Title</th><th>Size</th><th>Drawn by</th><th>Revision</th><th>Drawn Date</th></tr>
        </thead>    
        <tbody> &nbsp;
        <?php
            if(!empty($result))
            {
                foreach($result as $row)
                { 
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row->project_no . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row->sws_dwg_no . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row->client_dwg_no . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row->dwg_title . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row->dwg_size . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row->dwg_by . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row->dwg_rev . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . date('Y/m/d', strtotime($row->dwg_date)) . "</td>"; 
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
            }

        ?>
        </tbody>
       </table>

       <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>

</div>
```

The problem I see is that when I click the next page number, the page is refreshed and the dropdown select goes back to the default value and this is then submitted to the controller. The controller can't submit anything to the model to retrieve from the db.

So how can I overcome this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you can pass your project number by using `URI Segments`, in that way you can always access you selected project number without posting or using a post method.

```
public function dwg_list($porject_no){
    echo $porject_no;
    ......
}
```

Example:
www.your-domain.com/controller/dwg_list/{project_no}

I hope this has given you some ideas.

Here is a link, that i think can help:

https://codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/controllers.html

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to pass the URI segment to the page and its almost working. I'm using `onchange` submit to submit the dropdown and I think that this what is tripping me up. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

maybe it makes sense you save current selection in a session variable in the form handler "dwg_issue/dwg_list"

```
$this->session->set_userdata('selectedDropDownItem',$receivedDropDownItem);
```

Whenever you render your view, you would look if the session variable 'selectedDropDownItem' is set, and then while writing your ...  you would print the "selected" option.

Look at this...

```
echo "<select>";
foreach ($selectOptions as $as){
            //check session if default option set....
            if (isset($this->session->userdata['selectedOption'])){
                $defOption = $this->session_userdata['selectedOption'];
            }else{
                  $defOption= "";
            }


            if (!strcmp($defOption,$as)){ // if the current option is equal to the session stored option...
                echo "<option value=\"".$as."\" selected=\"selected\">".$as."</option>";
            }else{
                echo "<option value=\"".$as."\">".$as."</option>";  
            }           
        }
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: It s great idea to use the users session variable. If the user leaves the page or clicks on another link then the session variable must flushed or killed - how would I do that?

Comment: You would delete the session data in your view_file after you read the session variable for defining default value in selection box.   You can use $this->session->unset_userdata('some_name'); look for this in CI user guide